# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matching handler method found for servlet request

Tags: spring-mvc

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/urllink.ws', method 'POST', parameters map['HANDSHAKE_VAL' -> array<String>['jo65az2ADhnxu8vBdqJksi5XoKw%2F0jBTif3pvp8zEIULLsh%2F3A9pth27Bf6%2BGNa3s7XgNeACVWselRQQ7qy1wohOflJtzp29Oej%2Fvy%2BWTXKst09KLs0mIS7tPB6WX5jfUifzEwUFcVQWGKFJr4GYfMmBj9g8EAGDmQcB%2BvWf6L4DFo79Bu8UpyHwpylyJNj1Ek7VeLZjpvQhueDEU1PGb51cPAqMqc9NgLMMh5mpFQDVWvM0kNNrekLt7vOIIH1PweLHjmmto3RAV%2BuHVCHkyzYsPstTRdQSGuXfAgoLjERx3Ofe2V9edYJy5AsJLvm7%2BpxrfgRyTP%2BiA5EcAzmnA%2BLGGqBPGIGNCFZ03XeynDA%3D']]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$HandlerMethodResolver.resolveHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:448)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.IPAddressFilter.doFilter(IPAddressFilter.java:254)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:229)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:286)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.SchemaDetectFilter.doFilter(SchemaDetectFilter.java:225)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)






Request not Hitting in Contoller
Request contain an AES Encrypted data only


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/urllink.ws")
    public ModelAndView doLogon(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam("HANDSHAKE_VAL") String encryptedData, HttpSession session) {
        Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        //String myKey = UserOptions.getInstance().getSsoSecurityKey();
        //String URL = UserOptions.getInstance().getRbxUrlForInterfaceUpdate();
```

Comment: All you need to do is to read the error message: `No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/urllink.ws', **method 'POST'** (emphasis mine). Your code uses @RequestMapping(**method = RequestMethod.GET**, value = "/urllink.ws") (emphasis mine)

Comment: is "/urllink.ws" not working?